# Lose focus when spawning process in neovim

Tags: window-focus, neovim, xdotools

I'd like to implement a new workflow for Graphviz in Neovim. Essentially, I want to compile Graphviz and display the results in a live preview using Evince or Zathura. For '.dot' files, I've mapped `<leader>c` as follows:

```
autocmd FileType dot nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :w <bar> :!neato '%' -Tpdf -o '%:r.pdf' && evince '%:r.pdf' & <CR>
```

This saves the file, calls 'neato' to compile the graph, and runs Evince in the background. While this works as intended, it's distracting because it causes me to lose focus from Neovim to Evince. Is there a way to keep focus on Neovim? I am also concerned about potentially spawning multiple background processes of Evince. Can it happen ?

EDIT (SOLVED):
I finally solved it using xdotool. First, I saved the ID of the window where the terminal with Neovim is running. Then, I launched Evince and, after a brief pause, changed the focus back to the saved window.

```
autocmd FileType dot nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :w <bar> :!neato '%' -Tpdf -o '%:r.pdf' && id=$(xdotool getwindowfocus);evince '%:r.pdf' & sleep 0.4; xdotool windowactivate $id <CR>
```